# jquery and iscroll

Tags: jquery, iscroll4

I have links in the footer and they go like this:
`<a href="#index">Home</a> <a href="#page2">Page2</a>`

Where is the content held for page 2?  If all my stuff in page is in page2.php??

Answer (score 0):

If in the current page you had something like

```
<div id="page2">
     blah
</div>
```

When you clicked on that link it will scroll you to the div.

Comment: This is my first mobile application.  So then I will have ALL my content in 1 file?

Answer (score 0):

If all your content is on page2.php, it should be there. just put a link to page2.php.
Page2.php should normally have an include file like header and footer.

If your page2 content is in your curent page your href are correct

```
 <a href="#index">Home</a> <a href="#page2">Page2</a>
```

just put a  or any other tag it should go to there

Comment: Yes, but when launched from homescreen on iphone, it starts in a new window if I put a normal link.

Comment: It launches a new safari window*

Comment: normally it shouldn't if you havent put target="_blank, what do you want to achieve anyway. scrolling to your content?

Comment: I had a regular link, no target="blank"  If I have a div header, div content, and div footer.. the div header/footer are fixed and the content scrolls just fine.  How can I only load stuff into the "content" by clicking links in footer?  But loading actual pages there?

Answer (score 0):

You can have use jQuery .load() to load from other pages/files.

[jQuery Docs .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Here is an example:

> $('#content').load('page2.php');